# Maven plugin to check if a module's build it recent, and skip if thats the case

Tags: maven, maven-plugin

I have a huge multi-module project , which is being built using maven.

Most of them are core modules , which are used in other modules for various purposes.

But , 9 of 10 times, there is no change in the core modules and there is just some change in the depending modules.
Sometimes, there might be a small change in 1 core module of the many.

The issue is, I want maven to know, if the current build in target folder of the core modules is the latest accroding to the code, i.e no changes were made to the core for that.If thats the case, then I want maven to skip building that module during the maven phases.except the assembly plugin phase, which takes care of assembling all my modules at one place.

Is there a neat way to do this.I.e some maven plugin already taking care of stuff like this??

Some light on this will be great help.

Thanks,
Neeraj

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be you can use the [maven incremental build plugin](http://maven-incremental-build.java.net/site/usage.html) or use Hudson/Jenkins to do an incremtal build.

Answer (score 0):

Just use Hudson - it will scan your source repository for changes and only run a build once that has occurred.  It works well with Maven out of the box too.